# Class variables are not visible inside element event?

Tags: javascript, html, class, user-interface, visibility

I am hoping to create a web application, this means that the HTML elements will have to be pretty dynamic as they will be being created and moved around being handled by different other elements a lot.
I therefore decided to use classes - with a lot of success, until the point of handling events..This is the class in suspicion that Chrome tells me confuses it with a variable not being defined.

```
function SpanInputPair(element) {
    span = document.createElement("span");
    this.Span = getNextInputID();
    span.style.display = "none";
    span.id = this.Span;
    element.appendChild(span);
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    this.Input = getNextInputID(); // request a new ID for this element and save into this class
    input.id = this.Input; // Attach it onto the element for future finding :/ (slow)
    element.appendChild(input);
    input.focus();
    span.onclick  = function() {
        var input = getInput(this.Input); // this.Input cannot be seen?
        var span = getInput(this.Span);
        input.value = span.innerHTML;
        toggleDisplay(input);
        toggleDisplay(span);
        input.focus();
    }
    input.onblur...
```

The line "var input = getInput(this.Input);" is the issue as Chrome is telling me it doesn't see "this.Input" anymore. I know this because I can run this line and replace "this.Input" with the real value and it returns the element fine.
As you can see I have it creating a text box and span dynamically and setting their IDs for future use, this is because I previously tried to save the element itself in the class and use that inside the event - same issue, so I tried to find it in the document each event instead by using document.getElementByID().
Weirdly also it does not seem to focus the text box it just created (if that may be part of the issue too I don't know).
This project was created entirely from nothing and uses no libraries.
So my question is, can you please explain why the element's event cannot see any variables in the class that created it? And how could I fix this?

I have not yet seen this posted as many people are using a library such as JQuery and/or not using classes, is question is specific to event handling with help from internal variables of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it may not make too much sense, it is normal in JavaScript because the value of this has changed within the local function you have declared. Therefore, you must understand properly how to declare and use functions in JavaScript:

Functions in JavaScript has something called **context**, which just means that every function is bounded to a specific object. If we declare a function in your script, it will be bounded to the global object (which is window in browsers).

However, if we try to declare a **method** (a function that belongs to an object), 
`this` will be a magic variable that represents the object itself. Everytime you invoke `this.my_property`, you would get the value of the property of your object, either an "attribute" or a "method".

Therefore, the **function's context can be changed, as it happens with event handlers**. In your scenario, event handlers are functions whose context has changed, so everytime you access to this, its value will be the HTMLElement object that receives the event when you click on it.

To solve this problem, you can declare an auxiliary variable and use it inside of the handler. The common practice followed by the community is:

```
var that = this;   // Also, the people use 'self' instead of 'that'

span.onclick = function() {
   var input = that.input;

   // ...
};
```

Using this workaround, you will not have any problem.

Comment: The `this` value is going to be the `span` element, not `window`.

Comment: True, that was a big mistake. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation of how functions create their own "this", it does make sense as I am using functions as classes in the first place. However now the span and input elements stored in that class are being overwritten by every new instance of SpanInputPair, resulting in the input and span not being instance based..doesn't this means that I NEED to use "this"?

Comment: @LeeAllan if they are instance-based, the code is correct. But if they are class-based, you must store those values in SpanInputPair's prototype. So, you will have to do: `SpanInputPair.prototype.Input = getNextInputID();`

Comment: albertoblaz: That would update the ID for all instances of `SpanInputPair`. @LeeAllan is probably not using `new` when invoking `SpanInputPair`, making `this` the `window` object.

Comment: I am using `new` when creating a new SpanInputPair, I will look into exactly what prototype is, from what I know it is basically the static group of the class - which I don have use for at the moment as all input and span IDs are different. On another hand `var self = this;` is very useful for having access to containing classes, thanks.

Comment: OK, after some messing I see what you meant, apparently non `self` variables in a class do not get overwritten if the object is defined as new, I previously thought it always overwrote them (classic `var`s). I now have working..separate SpanInputPairs.

Answer (score 1):

The value of 'this' inside the click function is the element clicked. Here that would be the `<span>` you just created.

You are wanting the value of the this back when you defined the click function. (The question might also be: *What is the value of 'this' when the `SpanInputPair` function is called?* You may want to consider that.)

You can do that by something like this which adds it to the closure:

```
var thisInput = this.Input;
...

span.onclick  = function() {
    var input = getInput(thisInput);
```

You are going to have the same problem with `this.Span` on the next line.